# laravel 5.3 can't access property after loading a relationship via accessor

Tags: php, laravel, accessor

Initially, i needed to get the average rating from a reviews table for all products. I've founded the way how to do it, but i am stuck for hours when i want to access the accessors value. I want to display to the view the content of aggregate,but every thing i've tried, dosen't work. Please help.

Product model

```
protected $table = 'products';

protected $fillable = ['title','body'];



public function scopeActive($query, $default = true){
    $query->where('active',$default)->orderBy('created_at','desc');
}

public function productreviews(){
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
}

public function avgRating(){

    return $this->hasOne(Review::class)->selectraw('avg(rating) as aggregate,product_id')->groupBy('product_id');
}


public function getAverageAttribute(){

    if (!$this->relationLoaded('avgRating')){
        $this->load('avgRating');
    }
    $relation = $this->getRelation('avgRating');

     return ($relation) ? $relation->aggregate : null;
}
```

Review model

```
protected $table = 'reviews';

protected $fillable = ['user_id','body','rating'];

public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

ProductsController

```
 public function show(Product $product){
   $getAllProducts = $product->with('avgRating')->active()->get();
   return view('products.allproducts',['products'=>$getAllProducts]);
```

}

Returned Response from show method

```
    [{"id":1,"title":"Ipsum quos libero iusto.","body":"Ipsum temporibus              tenetur voluptates.","active":1,"created_at":"2016-11-23   12:44:02","updated_at":"2016-11-23 12:44:02","avg_rating":{"aggregate":4.5,"product_id":1}},{"id":2,"title":"Ab ducimus quia sed quia pariatur officiis.","body":"Cupiditate aut nihil at est.","active":1,"created_at":"2016-11-23 12:44:02","updated_at":"2016-11-23 12:44:02","avg_rating":{"aggregate":4,"product_id":2}}]
```

View

```
 @extends('layouts.app')
 @section('content')
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Products</div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                @foreach($products as $product)

                        @if($product->active)
                        <div class='alert alert-info'>
                            <h1>{{ $product->title}}</h1>
                            <p>{{ $product->body }}</p>
                            <p>{{ $product->avg_rating->aggregate }}</p>   
                        </div>
                        @endif


                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is writing the function this way:

```
public function avgRating() {
    return $this->productreviews()->avg('rating');
}
```

Comment: this dosen't help. it's showing this error:FatalThrowableError in Builder.php line 674:
Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on float

Comment: Have you tried without the parentheses? Like this: 
$this->productreviews->avg('rating')

Comment: public function ScopeAvgRating($query) {
    return $query->productreviews()->avg('rating');
}

Comment: errors,errors. BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2448:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::productreviews()

Comment: i've founded the solution. One active product had the rating set to null as default. That is why is encountered the error: can't access a property of a non object. @Yohanan Baruchel Thanks for your solutions.